# How to find the closest input name attribute value

Tags: jquery

given the following html:

```
<input name="name goes here" type="text" value="value goes here">
<span class="suggestInput" data-type="tag">
<img src="../images/icons/wand.png" title="Suggest an input" alt="">
</span>
```

im trying to find the name attribute value of the closest input, the one above the class 'suggestInput' above. In my example, it should return **name goes here**

I've tried:

```
$(".suggestInput").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

   var test1 = $(this).closest("input").attr("name");
   var test2 = console.log($(this).find().closest("input").attr("name"));
});
```

and they both return 'undefined' ..

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is used to find an ancestor element, in your case the input element is not a ancestor element of the `span.suggestInput` element, it is the previous sibling so use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to find it

```
var test1 = $(this).prev("input").attr("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.prev()` here because `input` is the immediate previous sibling of your span:

```
var test1 = $(this).prev().attr("name");
```

`.closest()` is not working because this method will traverse up the DOM tree and get closest matching ancestor which is not applicable in your case:

Comment: I don't notice that I need to key in the SO verification since I'm answering another question at the same time.